# try except block in python

Tags: python, exception

How could I code this in python "try except block?
I am to enter a series of numbers to calculate their sum. I want to input the Last digit with "ctrl +d" and then the program should give me the sum of the numbers entered.

```
sum = 0
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter a number: ")) 
        sum += n
    except(EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
        print(f"Sum of inputs is: {sum}")
        break
```

That is my code above.

What is wrong with that code?

I am not getting what I want.

I do not want the program to prompt me before I type "ctrl + d"
I am to type in my last input(digit) in addition to "crtl+d" and the program would print the sum of all numbers for me.

Comment: I believe ctrl-d only works if it is the first and only character in the input.  You can't type a digit plus ctrl-d.

Comment: @Mensart Do you know beforehand how many numbers you want to sum?

Comment: So are you saying you want to type the last number and press Ctrl+D (instead of Enter) and your program should still read the number that was typed?

Comment: p.s. When you added the comment, you removed the code formatting. Please fix it.

Comment: Do you want to do this in interactive terminal? Or are you redirecting stdin from a file?

Comment: You can't actually catch EOF. If you try `character = sys.stdin.read(1)`, it won't read anything until a newline is pressed.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice anything I could do to get the last input added to sum without the program repromt me

Comment: @Oda
Please, The user does not know how many numbers you want to sum.

Comment: @Eric Jin
I am using an online Ide. I am entrying the input  from the terminal

Comment: Does it have to be control-d? Would you be fine with using something like what C does, where a special character, maybe `.` is the terminator?

Comment: @Mensart The problem is that if you type something and then press Ctrl+D, python has no way to get what you typed. At least not with `input()`. There may be another way, but I don't know it.

Comment: What if I  make a dictionary